# Probability and Thermodynamics: Analysing feasibility of 50 benches problem

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, probability

Question:

I have a thought experiment that involves dropping 50 benches from a height through an open roof and examining the probability of them spontaneously arranging themselves into neat rows and columns. This scenario raises questions at the intersection of mathematics and physics. Here's the setup:

Imagine an idealized scenario where there are:

- 50 identical benches.
- An isolated system with no dissipative forces.
- A closed and perfectly athermic enclosure.
- A defined temperature for the system.

Given these conditions, the probability of the benches forming ordered rows and columns seems to defy our intuition and the second law of thermodynamics.

Here are my questions:

1. **Mathematical Feasibility:** Can we mathematically calculate the probability of the benches arranging themselves into ordered rows and columns under these idealized conditions, and if so, what mathematical tools or concepts should be employed?
2. **Physical Realism:** From a physics perspective, is this scenario truly feasible, or does it run counter to established principles like the second law of thermodynamics? How do we reconcile the apparent violation of this law in this thought experiment?
3. **Limits of Idealization:** To what extent do the idealized conditions imposed on this scenario (perfect isolation, closed athermic walls, etc.) affect the theoretical feasibility, and how does this relate to the real-world limitations and observations?

I'm a high school student and I was recently introduced to entropy which I found really fascinating and am interested in gaining insights into the theoretical aspects of this problem from both mathematical and physical perspectives, as well as understanding the boundary between idealized theoretical constructs and the practical realities governed by physical laws.

Comment: A slightly more feasible version of this is to take a pound of dried (straight) spaghetti noodles and drop them randomly into a large box.

Comment: [no dissipative forces] Whatever arrangement these (unphysical indestructible perfectly elastic) benches are in at a particular time, they won't be in it a moment later, since you have energy, no way to dissipate the energy, and you start the experiment without an equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about the probability of random events producing order. This is the right thing to think about for entropy. But your example isn't ideal for learning about the topic. It has too many details that need to be handled, but don't tell you anything important about entropy and order. For example, how top heavy is the bench? That affects the probability of it landing upright.

It should not be surprising that better examples are text book examples. That is why they are in text books.

For example, you have a room full of molecules that wander around randomly. What is the chance that they all wander into the same half of the room at the same time?

An example that doesn't leave a vacuum is suppose you have a room full of two different kinds of molecules. What is the chance that type A will wander into one half and type B will wander into the other?